# Why is jQuery, Rails and Chrome submitting sporadically?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, submit

So many problems trying to get a text link to submit a form in Chrome using Rails and jQuery.

I have tried many combinations and the one that seemed to work best in Chorme is:

```
$('form:first').trigger('submit')
```

It's crazy... Why would it work on the first time and second and sometimes third time, but then stop working?

Here is the Rails code that renders the text link submit button:

```
<li><%= link_to raw("<span class='button approve'><span><span>SAVE</span></span></span>"), "index_users", :onclick=>"$('form:first').trigger('submit')"%></li>
```

I tried this code too with the same type of sporadic results in Chrome:

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Edited:

This is the what the form tag renders to:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" data-remote="true" class="search_form general_form" action="/settings/2/update_user" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

And here is what the text button renders to:

```
<li><a onclick="$(this).trigger('click');" href="index_users"><span class="button approve"><span><span>SAVE</span></span></span></a></li>
```

The onclick code is changing since I am trying everything I can find. Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Little confusing to see what you are trying to do with link_to raw. Why don't you first do something real simple with a submit form? I don't see a form or the action to that is serving the submit. etc

Comment: Thanks for the response... The rails code that renders the form is <% form_for(:user, :url => update_user_setting_path, :remote => true, :html => {:method => :post, :id => "form1", :class => "search_form general_form"}) do |f| %>

Comment: Which renders into this form tag <form method="post" id="form1" data-remote="true" class="search_form general_form" action="/settings/2/update_user" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();"
```

and I think the other key was to us "#"

<%= link_to raw("SAVE"), "#", :onclick=>"$(this).closest('form').submit();"%>

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is related to Javascript event listeners - hanging them correctly for UJS (which I assume you're invoking with the `data-remote="true"` attribute on your form) can be tricky.

What does your controller render on a user update? HTML? Javascript?